# Im trying to loop using foreach and use the method array_push()

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to loop and got the following error:

> array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

**My controller:**

```
public function ViewSponsorInfo($sponsor_id)
{
    $id = $sponsor_id;
    $user_id = User::where('id','=',$id)->get();
    $user_roles = [];
    foreach ($user_id as $id) {
        array_push($user_id, $id->role);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be you wanted to write `$user_roles` instead of `$user_id`?

Comment: yes. $user_id is not an array

Comment: Do this array_push($user_roles, $id->role);

Answer (score 0):

You have `$user_roles` and `$user_id` mixed up in your array push.

**Change:**

```
array_push($user_id, $id->role);
```

**to:**

```
array_push($user_roles, $id->role);
```

The first argument for array_push is the array into which you are pushing the item.  You're trying to push the user_id into the user object, which is not an array, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an Eloquent query that returns a [Illuminate\Support\Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#introduction), you could as well achieve it without looping:

```
$user_roles = User::where('id', '=', $id)->pluck('role');
```

Although that is not part of the question: I wonder why you expect more than 1 record to be returned when retrieving the user by *id*? Why not do

```
$user_roles = User::find($id)->role; // or: User::findOrFail($id)->role
```

instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try this man,

```
public function ViewSponsorInfo($sponsor_id)
{
 $id = $sponsor_id;
 $user_id = User::where('id','=',$id)->get();
 $user_roles = [];
 foreach ($user_id as $id) {
    array_push($user_roles, $id->role);
 }
}
```

or if you need key also try this

```
public function ViewSponsorInfo($sponsor_id)
{
 $id = $sponsor_id;
 $user_id = User::where('id','=',$id)->get();
 $user_roles = [];
 foreach ($user_id as $id) {
    array_push($user_roles, array('role' => $id->role));
 }
}
```